# Day to day profile stats?

Tags: feature-request

I'm trying to do a little bit of analysis of user activity on the site. I want to learn how asking, answering, commenting, chatting and performing other activities in this site is related to reputation, engagement etc.

Is there any way I can get access to these statistics, per user, even if they're anonymous. I don't need the actual name, only a reference to help differentiate one user from the other would be ok...

Comment: Might be able to get the info you want from the Data Explorer if you know SQL http://data.stackexchange.com/about

Comment: The more I know Stack Exchange, the more I like it. Thanks @BenBrocka, are there any rules for its use?

Comment: Not really, it's rate limited and the info you get is limited. The worst you can do is run a slow query

Comment: Haha, that was my first try SELECT * FROM USERS hahaha :) I'll try to come up with something interesting...